# What is the difference between context.push() and context.update() in Django Context

Tags: python, django, django-context

From the documentation, I understand that the context object is a stack. Then what are `push()` and `update()` doing with respect to this code segment? It is stated in the doc that `push()` and `update()` are similar but `update()` takes a dictionary as argument. Then why are we using them simultaneously here?

```
import django.template
import django.template.loader

def render(name, *values):
    ctx = django.template.Context()
    for d in values:
        ctx.push()
        ctx.update(d)

    t = django.template.loader.get_template(name)
    return str(t.render(ctx))
```

Also, what is the need of having context object as a stack?

Edit : I went through the doc again and found the `flatten()` function which flattens all the levels in the stack to make them comparable.

Comment: Thank you @Lonely Neuron for the edit.

Comment: You are welcome. As long as you take notes and properly format your next post, my work is done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference seems to be (also according to the [tests](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/template_tests/test_context.py#L22)) the way you pass arguments into the call. Update takes a dictionary while push takes keyword arguments.

And about the usefulness, the documentation says:

> Using a Context as a stack comes in handy in some custom template
>   tags.

Comment: The way I get this is Update = Push + Change. Is this correct ?

Comment: No, I think it is really the same, just the arguments passed (if any) are different.

Comment: Do you have any clue why both are being in the same iteraion used in this code segment here ? Wouldn't it create an empty level in the stack at every alternate position ?